# How to maintain a running balance in a month wise report

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, pivot

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
        YEAR (DateOfTransaction) AS year,
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DateOfTransaction), 3) AS month,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'credit%' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) - 
            SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'Debit%' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Balance 
     FROM 
        .............) AS t
PIVOT (SUM(balance) FOR month IN (jan, feb, march, ...., Dec)) AS pvt
```

This query returns a month-wise report account balance. I want a result is running balance.

Example:

January month I credit 5000, February month I credit 2000

My query result is

```
 year  jan   feb march...dec
 2014  5000  2000 null ..null
```

I want a result like this:

```
 year  jan   feb     march...dec
 2014  5000 7000     null ..null 
           (5000+2000)
```

Comment: This is straightforward in SQL server 2012, not so in 2008. Can you provide a simple table structure I can use to show you an example for 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT year,Jan = Jan, Feb = isnull(Jan,0)+isnull(Feb,0),....
FROM
    (SELECT 
        YEAR (DateOfTransaction) AS year,
        LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, DateOfTransaction), 3) AS month,
        SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'credit%' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) - 
            SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'Debit%' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Balance 
     FROM 
        .............) AS t
PIVOT (SUM(balance) FOR month IN (jan, feb, march, ...., Dec)) AS pvt)t
```

Or you can simply add a temp table which stores numbers from 1 to 12

```
inner join #temp on n>=datepart(mm,DateofTransaction) group by year(transaction), n
```

Comment: Please write expression for march: mar=?

Comment: Select YEAR (DateOfTransaction), left(datename(mm,dateadd(mm,n-1,0)),3) as month, SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'credit%' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) - 
            SUM(CASE WHEN TransTypeName LIKE 'Debit%' THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS Balance from Table inner join #temp on n > = datepart(mm,DateofTransaction) group by Year(dateoftransaction), n .....pivot

Comment: Your 1st query work gud,but 2014 dec month and 2015 jan month is not add.Pls tel this implementation

Comment: Now I using internet in admin account,I can't copy past.

Comment: Can you please write the select and group by statement. Also confirm whether temp table contains from 1 to 12.

Comment: using store procedure to solve this query,Its possible are not

Comment: This is a simple requirement and it is possible with stored procedure

Comment: Thank u,I will try using stored procedure